# Distribute a number equally in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to distribute a number equally into an array of a given size. If I have a number 10 and an array size of 3, then I should distribute it into an array as below:

```
x = [4, 3, 3]
```

Later if I want to increment the number by 1, then I should pick up (one of) the lowest number(s) from the array, and update them one after another.

```
x = [4, 4, 3]
```

Later if I want to increment the number by 2, then I should update the array as below:

```
x = [5, 4, 4]
```

UPDATE:

I was able to do the first part

```
def split_into n, p
  [n / p + 1] * (n % p) + [n / p] * (p - n % p)
end

split_into(10, 3) #=> [4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: @JoshBrody, I was able to do the first part but not the update part. Please see the update part in my question.

Comment: Does the order of the array matter at all?  Is the array always 3 items long?

Comment: order of the array does not matter and yes, the array is always 3 items.

Comment: `n.times { x[x.index(x.min)] += 1 }`

Comment: That worked. Thanks @StefanPochmann

Comment: Don't update your question with an answer. If you have one that you are satisfied with, then mark that one as accepted. If you had come up with your own one, then write that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way, repeat finding and incrementing the smallest number:

```
n.times { x[x.index(x.min)] += 1 }
```

Demo:

```
x = [0, 0, 0]
n = 10

n.times { x[x.index(x.min)] += 1 }
x #=> [4, 3, 3]

n = 4
n.times { x[x.index(x.min)] += 1 }
x #=> [5, 5, 4]
```

Another simple way, reusing your existing method, faster in case n is large:

```
x = split_into(x.sum + n, x.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to split something into even groups, use Rails' [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of):

```
(1..10).to_a.in_groups_of(3) #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, nil, nil]]
```

You can also specify not to nil-pad the end by providing a second parameter of `false`.

If you really want to know the size of the groups, you can get it using [`in_groups`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups) (slightly different than `in_groups_of`):

```
(1..10).to_a.in_groups(3, false).map(&:size) #=> [4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: At the time I wrote this answer, there was a ruby-on-rails tag.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `Array.new(10).in_groups(3, false).map(&:size)`

Comment: @StefanPochmann that's what `in_groups_of` would return but I'm using [`in_groups`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups) (without `_of`).

Comment: @Stefan, I've incorporated your idea to use `in_groups`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the quotient and remainder via [divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod):

```
q, r = 10.divmod(3)
#=> [3, 1]
```

And create the corresponding array via [`Array.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
Array.new(3) { |i| i < r ? q + 1 : q }
#=> [4, 3, 3]
```

As a method:

```
def split_into(n, p)
  q, r = n.divmod(p)
  Array.new(p) { |i| i < r ? q + 1 : q }
end

a = split_into(10, 3)
#=> [4, 3, 3]
```

To "increment" the array by `1`, you could add `1` it to the array's [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) and call `split_into` again:

```
a = split_into(a.sum + 1, a.size)
#=> [4, 4, 3]
```

same for `2`:

```
a = split_into(a.sum + 2, a.size)
#=> [5, 4, 4]
```